# prevent changing slide by clicking on mislider

Tags: slider

I am using "mislider" and it works perfect, but I have a problem with it. By default, clicking on an item,  changes current item to clicked item, but I want to open a link by clicking on an item.
What do you suggest to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but not sure that is best! Just delete following lines:

```
// Add click events to slides
    if ( o.slidesOnStage > 1 ) {
        o.slider.on( "click", o.options.selectorSlide, function( e ) {
            if ( $( this ).index() !== o.indexCurrent ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                o.autoplayOff();
                o.transition( $( this ).index(), false, o.autoplayOn( o.increment ) );
            }
        });
    }
```